# Will calling select()/pselect() in secondary thread cause primary thread to block?

Tags: c, io, pthreads, multiplexing

I have an application that I'm working on that requires a couple of secondary threads, and each will be responsible for a number of file handles (at least 1, upwards of 10). The file handles are not shared amongst the threads, so I don't have to worry about one secondary thread blocking the other when `select`ing to see what is ready to read/write. What I want to be sure of is that neither of the secondary threads will cause the main thread to stop executing while the `select`/`pselect` call is executing.

I would imagine that this is not a problem - one would imagine that such things would be done in, say, a web server - but I couldn't find anything that specifically said "yes, you can do this" when I Googled. Am I correct in my assumption that this will not cause any problems?

For clarification, what I have looks something like:

- Main thread of execution ( `select()` loop handling incoming command messages and outgoing responses )
- Secondary thread #1 ( `select()` loop providing a service )
- Secondary thread #2 ( `select()` loop providing another service )

As I previously mentioned, none of the file handles are shared amongst the threads - they are created, used, and destroyed within an individual thread, with the other threads ignorant of their existence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No you don't have to worry about them blocking the main thread.  I have used select in multiple threads in various projects.  As long as they have distinct FDSETS then you're fine and each one can be used like an independent event loop.

Comment: That was what I had thought, but the `select` man page mentions that it will block the *process* while it waits for a file descriptor to be ready (or timeout). That's why I was wondering if that was meant literally (the *process* gets blocked), or if it meant simply the current thread of execution.

Comment: @Will As SB mentions, just make sure that the file descriptors are different.

Comment: Here is the correct "man page" for `select`: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html You won't find "process" mentioned in it at all except in the change history section. On many systems such as Linux, you can install POSIX man pages which will appear as `man` section `3p`, which is very helpful since the vendor man pages tend to contain misleading information.

Comment: @R: +1 thanks. I hate when there's confusing/misleading documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't select supposed to block the whole process?
Have you tried to set the nonblocking mode on the socket?

Also, see select_tut manpage for some help.

Here's a relevant section from the `select_tut` manpage:

`So what is the point of select()?  Can't I just read and write to my descriptors whenever I want?  The point of select() is that it watches multiple descriptors at the same time and properly puts  the  process  to  sleep  if there  is  no activity.`

Comment: Sockets are nonblocking. I had read something in the select man page that it will block the process, which is what prompted my question.

Comment: Who packaged such a bad tutorial full of misinformation as a man page?